# Quickly create a list of sequential and non-sequential numbers in Python

Tags: python

In R, I can quickly create a list of sequential and non-sequential numbers like so:

```r
numbers <- c(1:5, 8, 12, 15:19)
numbers
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  8 12 15 16 17 18 19
```

Is there a similar method in Python? Everything I've seen seems to require a loop and/or multiple mechanisms to create this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unpack a range into a list.

```
>>> [*range(1, 6), 8, 12, *range(15, 20)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```